# How to typeset a complicated URL that contains special characters

Tags: urls, links

I want to typeset this link:
https://www.arm.com/company/news#t=allnews&sort=%40articledate%20descending
and I get an error because of the % char. I'm wondering if there is a way or a package to do that.

```
\textcolor{blue}{https://www.arm.com/company/news#t=allnews&sort=%40articledate%20descending}
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: there is an url package with an url command.

Comment: I'm already using the hyperref package with the url command, and it doesn't work + the suggested question does not answer mine.

Comment: Then please post some code (a [minimal (non-)working example](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-asked-to-write-a-minimal-working-example-mwe-what-is-that)) that shows your problem.

Comment: I have figured out a solution through the command (\href), and to skip the % char just put a (\) before the char in the link and it will open.

Comment: Only loading the `hyperref` package is not enough. You need to tell LaTeX that the next string is a URL, so either use `\url{https://www.arm.com/company/news#t=allnews&sort=%40articledate%20descending}` or (as link) `\href{www.arm.com/company/news#t=allnews&sort=%40articledate%20descending}{the text to be linked}` or something similar.

Comment: Thanks, Jasper it worked. The proposed error was because of using the \textcolor command alongside the \url command, so I recommend setting up the href settings in the preamble for colors of links and such.

Comment: When using both, `\textcolor` and `\url`, you should place the `\url` macro inside.